# desktop: div to contain 3 elements side by side

Tags: html, css, row

I need to have a div contain 3 elements side by side on one row.
The elements are an input, a label and another div.
The following code put 2 elements on one line and the third on a second line.
How can solve this issue?

thx.,

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#search {
  width: 200px;
  float: "left";
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.onoffswitch {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for Courses" />
  <label>Edit mode is</label>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: flex;`, and `flex-direction: row;` for your div.

```
div {
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:flex` property to the css of the div will work and if you doesn't want border to the third block as well then either specify class to div or take third block in span.

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}

#search {
  width: 200px;
  float: 'left';
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="search"
    name="search"
    placeholder="Search for Courses"
  />
  <label>Edit mode is</label>
  <span class="onoffswitch">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="onoffswitch"
      class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
      id="myonoffswitch"
      tabindex="0"
      checked
    />
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```